# Comparing values without including zero?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 6 double values x,y,z,a,b,c. I need to take minimum at every time they change.

So far, I used `Math.Min()` and I added them in a list by checking if not equals zero and used `List.min()`. But every time the values changed, list doesn't update itself.

The process is checking thousands of times, and I need a fast way.

1. check all variables.
2. if one or more of them is 0, don't compare it.
3. Take the minimum of other values.
4. repeat, when button pressed.

Code:

```
 private void calculateRatio()
 {
      xRatio = 100 * (xStepCount / xAbsoluteDelta);
      yRatio = 100 * (yStepCount / yAbsoluteDelta);
      zRatio = 100 * (zStepCount / zAbsoluteDelta);
      aRatio = 100 * (aStepCount / aAbsoluteDelta);
      bRatio = 100 * (bStepCount / bAbsoluteDelta);
      cRatio = 100 * (cStepCount / cAbsoluteDelta);
 }

 private void selectAxis()
 {  
     minRatio = 100 * (Math.Min((double)xRatio, Math.Min((double)yRatio,  Math.Min((double)zRatio, Math.Min((double)aRatio, Math.Min((double)bRatio, (double)cRatio))))));
 }
 //without including zero, by updating every time step count changed.
```

Comment: What is causing the values to change? What is monitoring for such changes? It sounds like the real problem is detecting the changes. Some code would help this question make more sense.

Comment: Also note that equality comparison of a double value may not provide the desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want an algorithm that can find the minimum value that is not zero? Try this:

```
IEnumerable<double> values = new[] { x, y, z, a, b, c };
double nonZeroMin = values.Where(v => v != 0).Min();
```

Comment: Is that updates values when values changed, as different from List?

Comment: @ithnegique No. You'll need some code that detects when the values change and takes action. Without seeing how *your* code is structured, that's difficult to recommend.

Comment: That code is like running a `for` loop with an `if`. It doesn't update, but runs on the values themselves, each time you press your button.

Comment: @ithnegique It sounds like you want some kind of data binding. What are you *really* trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I just need 2 things, first comparing must not include zero, and second when values change, minRatio must change.

Comment: @ithnegique My code accomplishes the first goal, but to do the second, you need to either implement some form of data-binding / observer pattern, or to monitor the values over time. What's wrong with simply running this code every time the user presses the button?

Comment: The button was an example, every time, when a step is performed, the ratio of that axis changes. So the elements in the list must change and comparisation must restart. A for loop or foreach may be used, I just wonder a way more simple than filling and clearing list. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: @ithnegique Running a for-loop will simply block the current thread until the loop is completed. If this is something like a dynamical simulation, you may want to use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). On every 'tic' of the timer (every X milliseconds), re-evaluate `minRatio`.